# Is French lemmatization available with Core NLP?

Tags: stanford-nlp

There seems to be a tagger for French, but I don't find any lemmatizer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge, there isn't a French lemmatizer in Stanford NLP. You can take a look at [Ahmet Aker's lemmatizer](http://staffwww.dcs.shef.ac.uk/people/A.Aker/activityNLPProjects.html) instead.